# partial search in a list of strings

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, search

I have a set of keys that are used as indexes for fast searching in my application.

At the moment, I can only search for complete strings and the maximum flexibility would be if I could search for partial strings which occur anywhere in the strings. Of course, the naive way to do this would be iterate over all the strings in the list and look for sub-strings. This would work but is probably too slow when the list starts to grow.

I read a bit about radix trees but this would only allow me to do partial matches from the start of the string and maybe also from the end of the string.

My question is what algorithms should I look at to solve the problem of partial match (not in one big document) but in a list of strings. Would this problem be easier if I kept a sorted list of strings? I can see this will be easier if the strings were the same length but for variable length strings I could not come up with a reasonable approach.

Comment: Sort the strings prior searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you kept one big string that has all of your strings in it, but with a specific delimiter?  find the index of your partial, substring from or to the index, then split on your delimiter.  You now have the index for the string.  Lather, rinse, repeat with the rest of the string (or use a regex to find all matches)

Answer (score 0):

Suffix trees and suffix arrays are useful when you want to quickly perform partial string matching.